# Interactive banner div with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to re-create an interactive full-width banner like the one seen at:

http://www.mooreblatch.com/

I have looked at the source and it seems to be a bespoke jquery code - is there an open-source solution to such a feature as my client wants something similar in his wordpress site.

I have no difficulty in incorporating this code into the site, but do not want to simply copy their source jquery and html as I do not believe in 'stealing' other peoples hard work!

Any suggestions or guidance on where to find such tools or plugins much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If we just give you the code, it would be 'stealing' from us as well. If you can show us the code you already have, we may be able to point you in the proper direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use flex slider? You can set it to a very large width and put it in a 100% width container div.

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

It is free and gpl so it is not stealing.
Download it, modify the css, set it to fade and u are done...

Comment: thanks! Just what I was after